# Unresolved dependencies trying to install build-essential on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, lubuntu, python-2.7

I am trying to install build-essential (NB: I want to install the getch module for use in python eventually) and apt-get returns an error because of unresolved dependencies which cannot be fixed because there seem to be broken packages.

I have a fairly cleen sources.list (I only sets up the whole linux system a few hours ago):

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

I have tried the usual tips&tricks (all with sudo):

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get upgrade
```

I get:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, 0 not upgraded
```

Next I tried

```
apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

Same Output as before.

I even tried to resolve the dependencies manually, but I didn't get very far, because at some point I install a package (gcc-4.8-base) and when I want to install the package which depends on it (that ist gcc-4.8) apt-get complains that gcc-4.8-base is missing... That was the point when my brains got really messed up.

Anyway, does anybody have any suggestions? Thank you very much!
Oh, and yes, I did read a lot of posts in this and other forums, still dont have a clue! Any advice is thus greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem: I installed aptitude

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

and then ran aptitude to install build-essential

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

it suggested to downgrade some packages (don't accept the first solution it proposes, I think the second or third solution was the one that worked). In case somebody stumbles upon the same problem - use aptitude - as somebody wrote in another forum it is like apt-get only smarter...